# Zend Framework: Can i just get GET params?

Tags: php, zend-framework

In Zend Framework, most of the time to get a param, i will use

```
// from controller
$this->getRequest()->getParam('key');
```

but how can i get just GET params using the 'Zend' way? Or do i just use `$_GET`? Is there any difference between

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('key');
```

vs

```
$_GET['key'];
```

Comment: I mostly just use ` $_GET ` , ` $this->getRequest()->getParams() ` I more often use to get variables out of the route

Comment: In your controller class, you can use `$this->_getParam('key')` instead of `$this->getRequest()->getParam('key')` -- it's a little shorter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `getQuery()`:

```
$this->_request->getQuery('key');
```

Other methods available include

- getParam()
- getQuery()
- getPost()
- getCookie()
- getServer()
- getEnv()

`getParam()` checks user params first, then $_GET, and then $_POST, returning the first match found or null.

Try to avoid accessing the superglobals directly.

Answer (score 13):

The main difference is that

```
$_GET['key'];
```

is a dependency on the environment. It requires the superglobal to be available and containing a key of that name. It's also just a simple array access, while

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('key');
```

is an API method call. Access to the Request is abstracted. There is no dependency on the actual environment. The Request object could be a mock. The `getParam` method will always return a value regardless whether it is from `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Putting an abstraction on top of the Request is better, because it allows for more decoupling, less dependencies and therefor makes your application easier to test and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

This works for ZF2

```
$this->params()->fromQuery('key', 1); // second argument is optional default paramter
```

Answer (score 0):

After studying [Zend 2's in depth data binding documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/data-binding.html), I've found that it is best to access parameters from the route via the automatically accessible [Params plugin](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Mvc.Controller.Plugin.Params.html). Utilizing this plugin, you can get a parameter as shown below from within a controller.

```
$this->params('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Zend Framework 1 there are two possibilities to define "visible" parameters.

https://subdomain.domain.tld(/module)/controller/name/parameter1/value1
https://subdomain.domain.tld(/module)/controller/name/?parameter2=value2

First `parameter1` is part of the URL path and second `parameter2` is a real `GET` parameter. Both will be returned if calling `$request->getParams()`. But only `parameter2` is returned when using `$request->getQuery()`. Because `parameter1` is not part of the query. It's part of the url, logical.

Now, I like the answer of `Ryan Chouinard` how to get the `parameter2` with `$request->getQuery()`. But `parameter1` behaves like a `GET` parameter and I want to treat them like that. So how can I get the visible `parameter1` and `parameter2` but not the additional hidden `parameter3` from the post data?

My only solution is a helper that clones the request and changes the so called `paramSources` (default: `['_GET', '_POST']`) to `['_GET']` and then use `getParam()` as regular...

```
/**
 * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request
 * @param string                       $param
 * @param mixed|null                   $default
 *
 * @return mixed|null
 */
function getVisibleParam(string $param, $default = null, Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request = null)
{
    if (
        !$request &&
        !($request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest())
    ) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('There is no request. Are you in a wrong context?');
    }

    $_request = clone $request;
    $_request->setParamSources(['_GET']);

    return $_request->getParam($param, $default);
}
```