# How to capture POST on checkout onpage with Magento_Payment_Block_Info

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

How to capture POST on checkout onpage with Magento_Payment_Block_Info?

```
class Ks_Gippayment_Block_Info extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{


protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('ks/info.phtml');
}
public function getSomePostData()
{

    //****direct get POST/GET data from onepage checkout
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
public function getSomePostData()
{
    //****direct get POST/GET data from onepage checkout
    if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('firstname')){  
    }
}
```

see [Zend Framework: Can i just get GET params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830856/zend-framework-can-i-just-get-get-params)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this method by using class

```
public function getSomePostData()
{



if(isset ($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $name=$_POST['firstname'];
       /**like that**/

    }

}
```

or You can pass as `function` from `button click`